# Cannot access non-static field 'lblSystemStatus' in static context

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, user-controls

I have seen numerous posts on this problem, none of which have assisted.
I have the simple following code:

```
private delegate void UpdateLabelCallback(Label lbLabel, string val);
```

A simple delegate to prevent Illegal Cross Thread Calls.

```
private static readonly System.Threading.Timer TimerHalfASecond = new System.Threading.Timer(HalfASecondCallback, null,
        500, Timeout.Infinite);
```

A threading timer

```
private static void HalfASecondCallback(object state)
{
    UpdateLabel(lblSystemStatus, Resources.DesktopClock_timerOneSecond_Tick_CPU__ + _cpu.GetCpuCounter().ToString() + @"%");
    TimerHalfASecond.Change(500, Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

The static `Threading.Timer` Callback. The `lblSystemStatus` is errored showing

> "cannot access non-static field 'lblSystemStatus' in static context"

```
private static void UpdateLabel(Label lbLabel, string val)
{
    if (lbLabel.InvokeRequired)
    {
        var d = new UpdateLabelCallback(UpdateLabel);
        lbLabel.Invoke(d, lbLabel, val);
    }
    else
    {

        lbLabel.Text = val;
    }
}
```

The static UpdateLabel method.

**So the question is:**
How can I update the labels on the control when they are not static and the callback demands that they are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring your timer as a `private static readonly`. I won't do that if the timer runs in an instance of the class (control). If you don't make it `static`, the other methods don't have to and you can safely use instance variables (if you have two class instances, the timer could clash).

Another way is to provide the `state` to the `Timer` constructor to include the label, or a `Func<Label` to retrieve the label. For the first option it means you have to delay the creation of the timer until the label was created.

Sample:

```
new System.Threading.Timer(HalfASecondCallback, this.lblStatusText,
    500, Timeout.Infinite);
```

Then your handler could be:

```
private static void HalfASecondCallback(object state)
{
    Label l = state as Label; // in fact lblSystemStatus

    if (l != null)
    {
        UpdateLabel(l, Resources.DesktopClock_timerOneSecond_Tick_CPU__ + _cpu.GetCpuCounter().ToString() + @"%");
        TimerHalfASecond.Change(500, Timeout.Infinite);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried - it does not require the Instantiation of Label l and the call back method no longer needs the static attribute.

Comment: Okay, that is a solution too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create some static field, assign your label to this field and use it in static context